# Finding Phone Number to test with

Tags: testing, ui-testing

I am not quite sure if this is a question for Stack Overflow, so if you think it's not, please just transfer it somewhere where it fits.

So, for my UI tests, I need 5 unique phone numbers *without* SMS receving capabilities. I need real, valid phone numbers, but at the same time, I don't want to get into legal trouble. Is there any "list" of such phone numbers I can use just for testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use xyz-555-1212 where xyz is an area code.  555 is a reserved exchange but a valid number.

You can also use 888-555-1212 which is the toll free directory assistance.